# Centering/Bottoming a stacked div?

Tags: css

I have a div setup like this:

```
<div class ="outer">
    <div class = "inner"></div>
</div>
```

With CSS like so:

```
.outer {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
}
.inner {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background: black;
opacity: .5;
}
```

So basically a div stacked on top of another div. However, I want the top div to be located at the bottom and centered of the parent div, as opposed to the top left. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the inner div absoutely positioned within the outer div, in this case, this should work:

```
.outer {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
}
.inner {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 50px;
background: black;
opacity: .5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give auter div position:relative

Give inner div position:absolute and bottom:0px; left:0px; or whatever place you like.

it's very important to give outer div position:relative. if not sometimes it will be working sometimes not. And of course it will not work in very old internet explorer like everything.

absolute elements dont have height so if you can not use specified (like height:120px) you are f***. You can do this only by javascript to check the height of one absolute element and adding it with special margins.

to be sure which container is on top if you have few inner you can use z-index.